Why is this error showing up when using the same number of placeholders and values?

"error":"more placeholders (?, ?, ?, ?) than values (6383000, 'Egg', 1, '2024-07-13 15:29:58')","success":false}

If item and quantity:
 db.execute("INSERT INTO grocery 
(user_id, item, quantity, timestamp) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
(user_id, item, quantity, datetime.now()))


Remove the parentheses around the 4 arguments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146038/more-placeholders-than-values-when-inserting-into-sqlite-database.

now have try on this , i think you have added a extra bracket in last line
so, just remove the  extra bracket on last line
I am sorry if my answer did not help .

db.execute("INSERT INTO grocery
(user_id, item, quantity, timestamp)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
(user_id, item, quantity, datetime.now())


There are 5 ( and 5 ).....
